# VB6 Runtime Type Retrieval

Tags: vb6, runtime

How can you obtain the Type (the name as a string is sufficient) of an Object in VB6 at runtime?

i.e. something like:

```
If Typeof(foobar) = "CommandButton" Then ...
```

**/EDIT:** to clarify, I need to check on Dynamically Typed objects. An example:

```
Dim y As Object 

Set y = CreateObject("SomeType")

Debug.Print( <The type name of> y)
```

Where the output would be "CommandButton"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is TypeName rather than TypeOf.

```
If TypeName(foobar) = "CommandButton" Then
   DoSomething
End If
```

Edit: What do you mean Dynamic Objects?  Do you mean objects created with
CreateObject(""), cause that should still work.

Edit:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim oObject As Object
    Set oObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Debug.Print "Object Type: " & TypeName(oObject)
End Sub
```

Outputs

`Object Type: FileSystemObject`

Comment: Maybe I should clarify my question, I want to know what a dynamically typed Object is, so using TypeName will (in my case) only return "Object".

Answer (score 3):

TypeName is what you want... Here is some example output:

VB6 Code:

```
Private Sub cmdCommand1_Click()
Dim a As Variant
Dim b As Variant
Dim c As Object
Dim d As Object
Dim e As Boolean

a = ""
b = 3
Set c = Me.cmdCommand1
Set d = CreateObject("Project1.Class1")
e = False

Debug.Print TypeName(a)
Debug.Print TypeName(b)
Debug.Print TypeName(c)
Debug.Print TypeName(d)
Debug.Print TypeName(e)
End Sub
```

Results:

```
String
Integer
CommandButton
Class1
Boolean
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a copy of VB6 to hand, but I think you need the

```
Typename()
```

function... I can see it in Excel VBA, so it's probably in the same runtime. Interestingly, the help seems to suggest that it shouldn't work for a user-defined type, but that's about the only way I ever *do* use it.

Excerpt from the help file:

> TypeName Function
>
> Returns a String that provides information about a variable.
>
> Syntax
>
> TypeName(varname)
>
> The required varname argument is a
>   Variant containing any variable except
>   a variable of a user-defined type.

Answer (score 0):

This should prove difficult, since in VB6 all objects are COM (`IDispatch`) things. Thus they are only an interface.

`TypeOf(object) is class` probably only does a COM get_interface call (I forgot the exact method name, sorry).